Не загружается style.css на wp по ftp
Перестал загружаться основной файл style.css на wp-сайт по ftp (Total Commander). Закачка просто зависает.
Все остальные файлы, в т.ч. другие css, загружаются. Попробовал другим ftp-менеджером - загружается. Что именно стало блокировать именно этот файл, не могу понять: ТС, WP (может какой секьюрити-плагин) или со стороны хостинга

Total Commander в логах пишет в чём проблема. Логи идут в окошке вверху. Ни ВП ни css тут не причём.

Застревает на 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for style.css
Закачка

Попробуйте passive mode включить или выключить. Иногда помогает с такими загадочными вещами.


Застревает на 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for style.css

Ты пытаешься передать файл в бинарном режиме. Измени на авто или поставь вручную текстовый

Стоит также проверить в настройках FTP расширения для текстового режима. При выборе "автоматически" покажется форма с назначенными расширениями.


Пробовал переключать режим обмена. Не помогло. Да и все прочие файлы (html, css, php) передаются без проблем. Поэтому и подумал, что проблема может быть внешней, если глючит передача только одного этого файла. Может, какое из расширений в WP блокирует его обработку. Порылся в настройках плагинов но не нашел

@Baddy ВП (как и любой другой php-скрипт) вообще ничего не знает про то что происходит по ftp. Это только сервер и клиент. Ошибка говорит, что ты передашь текст как бинарник. В общем делай эксперименты, проверяй файл. Создай пустой новый с тем же именем, и пр..

Помыкался с вариантами и решил тупо переустановить ТС. Потому что полезли и другие глюки с подключениями. Помогло. Всем спасибо

@Baddy на будущее: у ТС достаточно удалить конфиги, а не переустанавливать. Вообще рекомендую поизучать этот мегаполезный файлменеджер. Там столько вкусностей.... может даже заменить несколько программ и вообще облечет работу с виндой. На руборде полезный тред

С ТС живу лет 700. Хотя использую далеко не все возможности. Хватает. За конфиги свои, наоборот, молюсь. В них весь накопленный опыт и тончайшие настройки под себя, которые переношу с компа на комп и системы на систему. Проще тс переустановить )) заодно обновил версию. В любом случае спасибо
